# Windows Metro Get Default App Icon for File Extension

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to dynamically get the icon/image of the default application for a specific file type in a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call GetThumbnailAsync() on a StorageFile representing the file.